# Why isn't `join` part of the `Monad` class

Tags: haskell, monads

It is a well known fact that `(>>=)` can be implemented using `fmap` and `join` while `join` can be implemented using `>>=`. Is there any reason we don't define the `Monad` class with `join` included and using the following default definitions?

```
join x  = x >>= id
x >>= f = join $ f <$> x
```

This would allow a minimal definition to include either just `(>>=)` or `join`, instead of forcing `(>>=)`. Might be a bit helpful considering category theory tends to favour `join`.

The usual argument against modifying classes is that we break backwards compatibility. However, in this case, that wouldn't happen - we only add the possibility of defining `Monad` using `join`.

Comment: As you say, `(>>=) = join . fmap`, but before GHC 7.10 `Monad` was *not* automatically a functor. In that sense, we define both `join` and `fmap` within `bind`. It's also much easier sometimes to implement `>>=` than join. Try doing it for, say, the parser/state functor.

Comment: @AJFarmar I don't think `(>>=) = join . fmap` works. The arguments are flipped and there are some other problems. But good points!

Comment: Ah, you're right,  it's actually `(join .) . flip fmap`, but the idea was there, as you say.

Comment: @AJFarmar, it's better to go with `=<<`, which matches the rest of the world better. `f =<< m = join (fmap f m)` or `(=<<) f = join . fmap f`.

Comment: I'm closing this against a newer question because Alexis' answer there supersedes my answer here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That was meant to happen with the [Applicative-Monad proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) (which has made it to GHC 7.10). However, there is [a technical issue](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles2#join) involving [type roles](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles) in GHC which has postponed indefinitely the implementation of what you suggest.

Comment: And that's s terrible reason to exclude `join`.  It should be part of the Monad class.

Comment: @augustss, it's a *sad* reason, not a *bad* one. Being able to use generalized newtype deriving and coercions for monads is a good thing.

Comment: @dfeuer It's as you say, but one can simply define `join` independently and then use the identity `(>>=) = (join .) . flip fmap` as I pointed out above, so it's not that much of a problem.

Comment: @dfeuer I think it's a bad reason. GNTD is, IMO, implemented with an unsound hack.  And now they have constructed an elaborate type system to make the hack sound, and everyone has to pay for it.

Comment: @augustss, how do you think it should be handled? I agree that type roles are not quite the cleanest language feature ever.

Comment: @dfeuer There are two issues, how to decide which GNTD to accept and how to make zero cost coercions.  To decide if a newtype deriving is acceptable I think the compiler should construct an instance declaration and make sure it type checks.  This will rule out the bad cases, but also some good cases.  I'm willing to take that loss.  To get zero cost coercions you could still use coercions the way ghc does, but I would prefer the compiler recognizing identity functions and internally replacing them by coercions.  I consider the current ghc situation an abstraction leak.

Comment: As a person who only learned Haskell within the past year, and have researched this issue, I believe that adding join would be better _overall_, specifically it would *lower the bar of entry for people learning the language*. When I personally tried to learn monads, Bind was an extremely difficult topic to grasp. Then I learned about join, which was much easier to understand, and once I did I could understand bind by its definition in terms of join (and fmap). It would also make for newer users actually being able to implement Monads for practice without outside help.