# Applicative functors as monoidal functors

Tags: haskell, applicative

As mentioned in Hackage for [Applicative Functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html), they are strong lax monoidal functors. So why doesn't their definition in Haskell show it like so :

```
class Functor f => MonoidalApplicative f where
  mult :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
  unit :: a -> f a 

  starAp :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  starAp h x = fmap (uncurry ($)) (mult h x)
```

`<*>` (starAp) is easily reconstructed in terms of the multiplication and this definition looks simpler to me. For exemple, here is the Maybe instance :

```
instance MonoidalApplicative Maybe where
  mult (Just x) (Just y) = Just (x,y)
  mult _ _ = Nothing

  unit x = Just x
```

Comment: The `(<*>)` presentation tends to be more convenient in day-to-day programming, even though the `mult` one is indeed neater in some aspects (e.g. the applicative laws look nicer when expressed in its terms). This scenario is similar to the relationship betweeen `(>>=)` and `join`. Relevant blog post: http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/

Comment: Note: the monoidal presentation usually has `unit :: f ()`. `pure`, then, can be recovered through `pure x = fmap (const x) unit`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27262462/414413

Comment: Almost always the standard mathematical notation/convention is better (that is, more efficient) for proving things, but not necessarily so for programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments to your answer, there is similar story with `join` and `>>=`. When there're several semantically equivalent ways to define something it's better always to choose most efficient & pragmatic way. Haskell was designed to write code, not to prove things (though, somehow *Haskell* haven't still become very popular programming language unfortunately).

If `starAp` had default implementation almost nobody would implement it (just as it happens now with `>>` in `Monad` type class). But `<*>` is extremely useful operation. It is used in applicate & monadic parsers a lot (`megaparsec`, `attoparsec`, `optparse-applicative`) and I can't imagine my life w/o `liftA*` for joining things. And it is very important for this operation to be as efficient as possible. Implementing `starAp` as `fmap (uncurry ($)) (mult h x)` may bring hard times to inlining and optimizing things for compiler.

Moreover, representation of `Applicative` using `mult` and `unit` operations doesn't really solves any problems. Obviously, `mult = liftA2 (,)`. But your implementation with

`mult (Just x) (Just y) = Just (x,y)`

not fully correct. Because your implementation is not lazy enough. You will evaluate both cases when it may be enough to evaluate only one. So you still can mess up even with this simple function. Thus this representation is strictly worse.

Comment: But in the case of Monad `join` was actually supposed to be added to Monad with the AMP. It wasn't due to technical difficulties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552064/why-isnt-join-part-of-the-monad-class/31552223

Comment: So is it just a performance concern ? Then why not declare both `mult` and `<*>` in Applicative, each one calling the other, so that instances can choose which one to override (or both) ? Also, almost all calls I've seen to `<*>` are fully evaluated, giving as many values as the function has variables. For example with a 3-variable function, I prefer `liftA3 f x y z` to `f <$> x <*> y <*> z`. Then the performance expectations are on `liftA3` rather than `<*>`.

Comment: `liftA3 f x y z = f <$> x <*> y <*> z`, this function is not faster than `<*>`. And it can easily not fully evaluate something. Example: sum of two maybe's. `liftA2 (+) Nothing (Just $ 2^(2^100))` evaluates instantly while `liftA2 (+) (Just 3) (Just $ 2^(2^100))` will kill your machine. Very legit case. Why define both when `mult = liftA2 (,)` and such implementation is lazy enough? Allowing multiple functions inside one type class is error-prone approach. You can see another explanations here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Proposal/MonadOfNoReturn

Comment: There is a delicate issue here. If you allow unrestricted recursions and non-strictness, then Hask is not a category and  Applicatives are not even functors. See for example [Wader's remark](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) for a sufficient condition under which 'parametricity' holds in System-F like calculus, without which you can easily construct a 'counterexample' to (say) the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: So this is not only a performance concern, but also about correctness. In a sense Haskell's categorical definitions are a  declaration that 'this is a programming language, and may not be correct in a strictly mathematical sense'.