# I can't understand Wikipedia's definition of "applicative functor"

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

Studying functors, applicative functors and monads in Haskell, I found this definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor):

> In functional programming, specifically Haskell, an **applicative
>   functor** is a structure that is like a **monad** (`return`, `fmap`, `join`)
>   without `join`, or like a **functor** with `return`.

I can't understand: it seems to me that providing `return` (i.e. `pure`) to a functor is not sufficient to obtain an applicative functor, because you need to provide `ap` (i.e. `<*>`) too, which cannot be defined in terms of `fmap` and `return` only. Did I miss something or Wikipedia's definition is not absolutely correct?

EDIT 2017-02-08: I found other useful insights on this question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400846/applicative-functors-as-monoidal-functors) answer.

Comment: You are correct, as I agree that is a terrible definition for applicative functors. Without `<*>`, that definition seems incomplete. I am racking my brain to see if you could derive `<*>` just from return/fmap, and I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @haoformayor you cannot. Just [count the `f`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34933736/1139697): both `fmap` and `return` increase the count of `f`s in the type, whereas `<*>` keeps it constant.

Comment: I have to say, I've *never* understood wikipedia's definition of *any* advanced mathematical concept without already having at least some degree of understanding of it to start with.  I simply would never go there for this kind of learning, as  I would just end up getting very confused... even after @Zeta's edits I find the article very confusing.  So, it's a strong lax monoidal functor... but what does that mean?  The monoidal functor article doesn't help, because it suggests that "strong" and "lax" are mutually exclusive...

Comment: @PeriataBreatta someone should rewrite that article. Without Haskell knowledge, it's useless. With Haskell knowledge, it's mostly useless :/.

Comment: That article was suggesting a nice (but unfortunately wrong) thing: that there was a simple progression from functor to applicative and finally to monad, just by progressively adding class methods. Start with a functor with an fmap, then add a return and you get an applicative, then again add a join and you'll have a monad. That seemed nice to me, given that functor is a superclass of applicative which is in turn a superclass of monad; but it doesn't work with fmap, return and join. Maybe that could work with some other typeclass methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article was not correct. Assume we have a monad `m` without `join`, or a functor with `return`. We can define `pure` immediately:

```
pure :: Monad m => a -> m a
pure = return
```

We cannot, however, define `(<*>)` with `fmap` and `return` only. All we have is `fmap`, so we would end up with `m (m a)` if we try to use an `m (a -> b)`. At that point we need `join` or its equivalent `(>>=)`:

```
(<*>) :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
f <*> x = join (fmap (flip fmap x) f)

-- or, easier to read:
-- f <*> x = do
--   f' <- f
--   x' <- x
--   return f' x'
```

An applicative functor is like a functor with `return` and `ap`, but no `join`. So yes, you were completely right, Wikipedia missed the operation of applicative (see [the original paper](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf)).

By the way, if you add only `pure`, you get a [pointed functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed). The [typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Applicative) provides a better overview over `Applicative` than the Wikipedia article, though.

Comment: Note that I use "was not correct". I've took the courtesy to fix the article.

Comment: @adamse Whoops, accidentally used posted `(>>=)` instead of `(<*>)`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct, applicative functors require `<*>` as well as `pure` for a minimal definition.  It's worth noting that we can get `fmap` from those, though:

```
fmap f a = pure f <*> a
```

Similarly we can get the applicative definition from monads:

```
pure = return
f' <*> a' = do
    f <- f'
    a <- a'
    return $ f a
```

You could look at applicatives functors a generalization of functors to multi argument functions or as combining values with context horizontally:

```
liftA2 f a b = f <$> a <*> b
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (f a -> f b -> f c)
```