# Why did pointfree.io choose liftM2 instead of liftA2?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

I was recently writing a solution for the [ISBN Verifier](http://exercism.io/exercises/haskell/isbn-verifier/readme) exercise at [Exercism](http://exercism.io), and when I ran this function through [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io):

```
\c -> isDigit c || c == 'X'
```

I got back:

```
liftM2 (||) isDigit ('X' ==)
```

Why did pointfree.io choose `liftM2` from `Control.Monad` instead of `liftA2` from `Control.Applicative`?

Comment: `pointfree.io` is a fun toy, nothing else. It's shouldn't in any way be expected to give _good_ suggestions, it only hints what's possible.

Comment: I'm surprised it chose `('X' ==)` rather than `(== 'X')`. Obviously this transposition is "safe" because `(==)` is supposed to be symmetrical, but why wouldn't it just choose an exact transformation?

Comment: @amalloy I can't answer why that tool does it, but it is something I pay attention to myself when writing partial applications. As a rule of thumb, applying earlier arguments first is better, because carefully written functions may share more computation when given their first arguments than when dropped under a lambda. e.g. imagine if `(==)` first compared some expensive statistic about each argument, then continued with some other comparisons; then `map (foo==) bar` could be significantly more efficient than `map (==foo) bar` because the former computed `foo`'s statistic just once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact is that `Control.Monad` is much older than `Control.Applicative`.

Monads were already in Haskell 98, while the paper about applicative functors was introduced in 2007. The package in Hackage exists since 2005.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor#Relationship_to_monads):

> Due to historical accident, applicative functors were not implemented as a superclass of Monad, but as a separate type class. It turned out that, in practice, there was very little demand for such a separation, so in 2014, it was proposed to make Applicative retroactively a superclass of Monad.

So `liftM{N}` are still valid.

Comment: This answer is entirely correct. It is perhaps worth noting that the Wikipedia explanation is rather odd: "there was very little demand for such a separation" sounds like an euphemism, as the separation served no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @duplode, I think the explanation sounds wrong because `Applicative` was always (to the best of my knowledge) a subclass of `Functor`. It certainly was by `base-4.0.0.0`, back in 2009.

Comment: @dfeuer Oh wow, that's flat out wrong indeed. (I hadn't actually realised that page was also talking about `Functor`, due to a combination of late night posting and expecting to see the usual remarks about the AMP.)

Comment: @duplode, after checking through all the ancient documentation to verify that `Applicative` has been a subclass of `Functor` since its introduction in `base-4.0.0.0`, I edited Wikipedia to remove the very definite error. I think someone saw that the `Applicative` class stretched out in the original paper lacked a `Functor` superclass and got confused.

Comment: @dfeuer This conversation has reminded me that the *first* paragraph of that article [has also been recognised as nonsense for quite a while](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42043385/2751851). I have made a quick attempt at making it, if nothing else, correct.